# @ConditionalOnMissingBean and @ConditionalOnBean on the same type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got strange situation. I'm trying to write auto configuration class where I create bean if another bean exists or not so I've got conditional on bean and conditional on missing bean on same type..

Here is my code:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(
    type = {"com.example.Api"}
)
public ApiManager apiManager() {
    return new ApiManager() {
        public Result getValue(Request request) {
            throw new Exception("Api not provided.");
        }

        public Result setValue(Request request) {
            throw new Exception("Api not provided.");
        }
    };
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(
    type = {"com.example.Api"}
)
public ApiManager apiManager(Api api) {
    return new ApiManagerImpl(api);
}
```

The problem is that it does not check `@ConditionalOnBean` if it already checked in `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` that bean of type `com.example.Api` is not missing and then bean is not created.

And I get error like:

```
Parameter 2 of constructor in com.example.ServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.ApiManager' that could not be found.
- Bean method 'apiManager' in 'ApiAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.example.Api; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'api'
- Bean method 'apiManager' in 'ApiAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.example.Api; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'api'
```

Answer (score 3):

What you get is quite logical. Conditions are evaluated in order, that's why auto-configurations are processed after user-configuration.

If the context did what you're expecting, we'd have to evaluate all the conditions of all the bean definitions before doing anything. And that will defeat the purpose of an auto-configuration handling the fact a bean of a certain type was provided by a user (user config) or an auto-configuration.

You need to rewrite this auto-configuration to import things in order. One way to do that is to move each method on a package private config class and then do as follows:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ApiPresentConfiguration.class, ApiNotPresentConfiguration.class})
```

A better way to handle this really is to not do that at all and simply use `ObjectProvider`:

```
@Bean
public ApiManager apiManager(ObjectProvider<Api> api) {
    // Check if API is present and then return the appropriate implementation
}
```

Comment: I expected it working with `ObjectProvider` but still not working using conditionals... When using with `@Import` should I use inside `ApiPresentConfiguration` conditionals?

Comment: Import is just ordering how you want the conditions to be evaluated.

Comment: Using import it enters `ApiNotPresentConfiguration` but `Api` bean is created by another `AutoConfiguration` so the order is wrong yes? The `Api` `AutoConfiguration` should be exectued before `ApiMenagerAutoConfiguration` yes?

Answer (score 0):

try leveraging `@Primary`.

I am not sure how this would fit your use case but consider the following:

```java
@Bean
public ApiManager apiManager() {
    return new ApiManager() {
        public Result getValue(Request request) {
            throw new Exception("Api not provided.");
        }

        public Result setValue(Request request) {
            throw new Exception("Api not provided.");
        }
    };
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(
    type = {"com.example.Api"}
)
@Primary
public ApiManager apiManager(Api api) {
    return new ApiManagerImpl(api);
}
```

## Case 1: `Api` doesn't exist

1. First bean acts as the default one and is used.
2. Second bean is not created at all.

## Case 2: `Api` does exist

1. First bean is created (since it's the default) but not used.
2. Second bean is created and you end up with 2 beans of type `ApiManager`; but since it has `@Primary`; it will be used.